# Why cant i pass this variable from Javascript to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Whats wrong here? Im trying to use a JS function that transforms a string:

```
?>
//JS
<script type="text/javascript">
 var strIn = <?php echo json_encode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); ?>;
 var strKey = key
 Decrypt3 = function (strIn, strKey) {
  var strOut = new String();
  var lenIn = strIn.length;
  var lenKey = strKey.length;
  var i = 0;
  var numIn;
  var numKey;
  while (i < lenIn) {
    numIn = parseInt(strIn.substr(i, 2), 32);
    numKey = strKey.charCodeAt(i / 2 % lenKey);
    strOut += String.fromCharCode(numIn - numKey);
    i += 2;
  }
  return strOut;    
  $.post('shop_list.php', {variable: strOut}); 
};
</script>
//JS

<?php
$strOut = $_POST['strOut'];
```

And it gives me:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: strOut in <b>shop-list.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />
```

Isn't `strOut` correctly defind here? What i can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Are the two lines at the bottom part of shop_list.php?  Are the other lines part of a different page?

Comment: They are the on the same php file. Which is shop-list.php

Comment: In your code What's `key`?

Answer (score 2):

You're sending an object and the key is `variable`

```
$.post('shop_list.php', {variable: strOut});
```

which means it's accessible with

```
$strOut = $_POST['variable'];
```

`strOut` is just the javascript variable referencing the value

And you have to remove the return statement, otherwise the $.post function never runs

Comment: The POST request also happens *after* the return statement.

Comment: This gives me `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: variable in <b>shop-list.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />`

Comment: Then try debugging, add `print_r($_POST);` in the PHP file, and a success handler to see what is returned

Answer (score 0):

There are *a lot* of things wrong with your code. In no particular order:

1. The `Decrypt3` function is never called.
2. `$.post` is never called because it comes after the return statement. You probably intended the return statement to come after the POST request, like so:

   ```
   $.post('shop_list.php', {variable: strOut});
   return strOut;
   ```
3. The `json_encode()` variable will cause a syntax error. You have to throw it in quotes:

   ```
   var strIn = <?php echo "'", str_replace("'", "\\'", json_encode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)), "'"; ?>;
   ```
4. The `strIn` and `strKey` variables, defined outside the function, are never going to be used for anything. Inside the function they will be overridden by the function's arguments. You probably intended for them to be passed to the function, yes?
5. The `key` variable is undefined. Problematic.
6. When grabbing the variable in PHP you are using `$_POST['strOut']`, yet in your Javascript code you are sending it as `$_POST['variable']`. You should fix that.
7. The `numIn` variable is set to a JSON string, yet inside the function you are coercing it to an integer. That is not going to work. JSON strings, in PHP, look like `{...}` or `[...]`. That cannot be coerced into an integer.

I tried to refactor the code and this is what I came up with. It will probably not work (because of problem #7, for instance), but it was the best I could do to clean up the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Decrypt3(input, key) {
    var out = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += 2) {
        var numIn = parseInt(input.substr(i, 2), 32);
        var numKey = key.charCodeAt(i / 2 % key.length);
        out += String.fromCharCode(numIn - numKey);
    }
    $.post('shop_list.php', {strOut: out});
    return out;
};
var strIn = <?php echo str_replace("'", "\\'", json_encode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)); ?>;
var strKey = "KEY OF SOME KIND...";
Decrypt3(strIn, strKey);
</script>
<?php
$strOut = $_POST['strOut'];
?>
```